# Boto3 script to get network interface of ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I'm trying to write a boto3 script (needs to work with AWS lambda) which can extract the ENI attached to an ELB. Looking at the boto3 reference I've investigated 2 ways of getting this. Firstly using describe_load_balancers, there doesn't seem to be any information about the network interfaces in the output of this.

Secondly I've tried EC2.NetworkInterface(id), this however is the wrong way round for me as it can show the ELB's ENI but only when the ENI is specified in the class.

Answer (score 1):

AWS ELBs are pretty much black boxes are far as the user is concerned.  You can manage their configuration, but you can't get instance-level details the way you can for an EC2 instance though the SDK or any other means.

If you want the ENIs of the instances attached to the ELBs, you can get their instance IDs from `describe_load_balancers`, then use those in `ec2.describe_instances` to get the interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **describe_network_interfaces** of ec2 client in boto3 using 'description' in Filter parameters. This will return all the ENIs of the instances attached to the ELBs along with other details such as ipv4 addresses.

```
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')   
response = ec2.describe_network_interfaces(
        Filters=[
            {
                'Name': 'description',
                'Values': [
                    elbDescription,
                ]
            },
        ],
    )
```

Note: You can get the value of elbDescription in AWS EC2 console for your ELB.

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_network_interfaces